# How to run Opennms webapp from eclipse

Tags: opennms

I want make some modification in the OpenNMS web interface . So i downloaded the source code of OpenNMS and i import it as an existing maven Project in Eclipse.
I get this error in POM.xml
 com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamDriver
 Dependency to project opennms-services with type test-jar is not fully supported. Classpath and/or deployment issues might arise. Try Maven->Disable Workspace Resolution

I want to run Opennms or at least the web APP from Ecplise  and make some modification into it . What should i do ?
Thanks